# Ground state of the Jaynes-Cummings hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, hamiltonian, second-quantization, matter

Equation (5) in beautiful paper ([link](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/srep01180)) on Jaynes-Cummings Hamiltonian gives energy levels

$$E_n = n \hbar \omega \pm 2 g \sqrt{n}, \text{ where } n=0, 1, 2, \ldots$$

But eigenstates in Equation (4) are in basis of excited and photon and ground and photon:

$$|e,n\rangle \text{ and } |g, n-1\rangle.$$

So, what is meaning of the state with $n=0$, since eigenstate is $|g, n-1\rangle = |g, -1\rangle$ photon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ground state is pretty easy - the ground state of the atom, with no photons. This is pretty trivial to verify directly.

To be a bit more explicit, if you take the paper's hamiltonian,
$$
\mathcal H_\mathrm{sys} = \hbar\omega \sigma^+\sigma^- + (\hbar \omega-\Delta)a^\dagger a + g(\sigma^-a^\dagger+\sigma^+a),
$$
and apply it to the ground state $|g,0\rangle$, then it is easy to check explicitly that
$$
\mathcal H_\mathrm{sys}|g,0\rangle=0=0|g,0\rangle,
$$
since $\sigma^-|g,0\rangle = a|g,0\rangle = 0$. In particular, in *no* way does $a|g,0\rangle$ invoke states with negative numbers of photons.

The paper makes it clear, when it says

> with the exception of $n = 0$ which is unique,

that the ground state is *not* a part of any doublet of the form $|g,n\rangle \pm|e,n-1\rangle$, and that instead it sits on an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ (as opposed to the layering of the rest of the Hilbert space into the invariant subspaces $\mathrm{span}\mathopen{}\left(\{|g,n\rangle ,|e,n-1\rangle\}\right)$, of dimension $2$, for excitation number $n\geq1$).

The paper is maybe a bit terse when it explains it, which is par for the course because the material is standard and only needs to be laid out to fix the notation; as is, the explanation is sufficient by the normal standards of the literature. If you want an in-depth explanation of the diagonalization of the Jaynes-Cummings model, then the primary literature is not the place to look ─ instead, you should look for a suitable quantum optics textbook such as Gerry & Knight or Scully & Zubairy.

Comment: I have one very basic question about the third term in your equation: when it is written as: $g(\sigma_-a' + \sigma_+a)$, why don't we put a tensor product between $\sigma_-$ and $a$ also between $\sigma_+$ and $a$' since photon and the atom is in different space?

Comment: @j.doe because if we put tensor signs everywhere where they are vaguely applicable, instead of writing them when they are truly necessary and relying on context to convey those structures where it is clear enough on its own, the quantum mechanics literature would be 15% tensor-product signs.